# Sample size in A/B testing and its impact on test being positive

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, ab-test

1. How do I choose the right sample size for A/B test? looks like if I increase the sample size the test can always result in positive
2. Do we use t-test if my sample size is more than 30? because in t-test we use the standard error(SE) and the standard error will become small when the sample size is huge. if SE is less then my t-test will show positive.

looks like I am missing something, please help

Comment: To estimate the required sample size with depend on what you are measuring. Is it ratio or a measured value? The sample will also depend on how small of a difference you are looking to detect with a given confidence limit. If the difference is large between A vs B then a smaller sample size can be used to. If the difference is small, then a large number of samples is needed to separate the signal from the noise.

Comment: it is a measured value. In general, my understanding is more the sample size better my test result would be but, why is it not the case here?

Comment: I agree with you that larger the sample size the better.  I am not sure what you meant by " increase the sample size the test can always result in positive".  Also note that as sample size increases the t-test becomes more normal distribution.  Thus for greater than 30 samples the t-test and z-test becomes same test.

Comment: @Dave2e How do we A/B test for a ratio? can you please point to relevant material.

Comment: There are a couple of options depending on your data.  The basic is Z Score for 2 Population Proportions.  Another option is the Fisher Exact test.  With the Fisher's test You would have a 2x2 contingency table with the number of Yes and No for both your A and B conditions.